Why am I getting this error: Cannot update List`1: it has no PK
I have a model class built like this:
using SQLite;

public class PassMod
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Title { get; set; }
    public string? UsrName { get; set; }
    public string? Passwrd { get; set; }
    public string? SiteAddr { get; set; } 
    public int GrpId { get; set; }
    public string? Notes { get; set; }
}

Then I select a row from a datagrid and I pass that row to a popup screen. After editing all the data,  except the Id, I then click on a button that has this code-behind:
private async void btnUpdt_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<PassWrds> lst = new List<PassWrds>();

    lst.Add(new PassWrds()
    {
        Id = psWGp[0].Id,
        Title = pw.pwTitle,
        UsrName = pw.pwUsrname,
        Passwrd = newpasswrd,
        SiteAddr = pw.pwSiteaddr,
        GrpId = pw.gId,
        Notes = pw.pwNotes
    });

    await conn.UpdateAsync(lst);
}

pw. is the location of the view model to where the entry fields in the popup screen are binded.
await conn.UpdateAsync(lst); 
is where I get the error message. So where am I going wrong, and how can I fix it?

What db framework?

Id might simply not be defined as PK in the database.

I'm using .NET 8.0

Yes, but the question is what Database framework you are using (EF Core, Dapper, ...)?

I think the problem is in how you declared your primary key. Try this:
public class PassMod
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // Some attributes
}

In this way, EF Core already understands that it is auto increment.
It might be interesting to use the long type as the primary key instead of int.
Int is 32 bits long, while long is 64 bits long. This will limit the maximum number of records if this table grows too much.

I tried this out. I deleted my database and created a new one. And when I did, each Id field was populated with 0.00. Now I added 3 group names after I created the database. So should I be adding something else to the model class or should I be manually incrementing the Id field myself?

The database itself is responsible for the auto-increment. Whenever I used EF Core, I always implemented the primary key as a long type instead of an int.
You would have to check how EF created the migration to understand what is happening.
